# Chrome request from an intranet site to localhost

Tags: google-chrome, security, csrf, intranet

Our application consists of two components. There is an intranet website running on the IP address 192.168.1.189 and a desktop tool that runs a simple web server on a user's computer. The desktop tool is used to sign documents with a certificate that is saved on a USB token. The mechanism of signature is that the website sends a request using the HTTP protocol to `127.0.0.1` and receives the signed document as a response. Currently, I see the following text when the request is sent.

> [Deprecation] The website requested a subresource from a network that it could only access because of its users' privileged network position. These requests expose non-public devices and servers to the internet, increasing the risk of a cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack, and/or information leakage. To mitigate these risks, Chrome deprecates requests to non-public subresources when initiated from non-secure contexts, and will start blocking them in Chrome 92 (July 2021). See https://chromestatus.com/feature/5436853517811712 for more details.

I have Chrome 94 currently installed. I read the referenced document and the private network is distinguised from the publi internet. However, I am still not sure whether the request from 192.168.1.189 to 127.0.0.1 is going to be blocked in the future. So is it going to be blocked?